# Selenium How do I Open Browser with my Profile?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my selenium script, I am trying to open chromium as a certain user, instead of signed out, but when I run the script, a new browser is opened, but still signed out. The interesting part (for me at least), is that no error gets thrown, and when I check the console it only says the script was started.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/pi/.config/chromium/Profile 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver',options=options)
```

I got the profile path, or what I presume the path to be, by typing chrome://version, and copying the path

This is being run on a raspberry pi (debian) on python 3.7.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!